# Hyperbolic functions and sequence and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, hyperbolic-functions

Using these identities:

1. sinh(mx+x)=cosh(mx)sinh(x)+sinh(mx)cosh(x)
2. cosh(mx+x)=cosh(mx)cosh(x)+sinh(mx)sinh(x)
   Express the following sums in terms of just cosh((n+1)x), sinh((n+1)x), cosh(x) and sinh(x):
3. Cn=cosh(1x)+cosh(2x)+cosh(3x)+...cosh(nx)
4. Sn=sinh(1x)+sinh(2x)+sinh(3x)+...sinh(nx)

Looking for full worked answer.

Comment: On what lines have you tried ?   Please show that so that someone can help you. Also please use MathJax to format expressions

Comment: Duplicate [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427910/express-the-following-sums-of-coshnx-and-sinhnx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, consider that $$\sinh(n+1)x-\sinh(n-1)x=2\cosh nx\sinh x$$
So if you now consider $$2C_n\sinh x=(\sinh 2x-\sinh 0)+(\sinh 3x-\sinh x)+(\sinh 4x-\sinh 2x)+...$$
This is a telescoping sum which leaves you with $$2C_n\sinh x=\sinh (n+1)x+\sinh nx-\sinh x$$ and hence you have the required sum.

The other one can be done in a similar way.

Comment: Have a look at $\cosh(n+1)x-\cosh(n-1)x$

Comment: Also is there a reason why you don't include n=0 for the series when subbing it into 2Cnsinh(x) which would give you sinh(x)-sinh(-x) which would give you an extra 2sinh(x) to the required sum? Thanks

Comment: The first term is with n=1